# OpenLayers: When is a click a pan?

Tags: openlayers

Is there a way in OpenLayers (v3.0.1) to set the threshold / tolerance of how many pixels of "dragging" it takes to start panning?

Some of our users use the map with a touchscreen device and a stylus (pen) to select features and pan the map. Now with the stylus, when they "click" they seem to drag a few pixels and the map reacts with panning instead of a select/click event.

Edit: I'm using the select-interaction for the "clicking"/"selecting".

Comment: Are you using `singleClick` as a `condition` to the interaction?

Comment: No I'm using `click` as `condition` so it doesn't delay to find out if it's a dblclick. I think the behaviour is the same though because in an earlier version I used singleClick and experienced the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenLayers v4.2.0 a new option was introduced:

> `moveTolerance`: The minimum distance in pixels the cursor must move to be detected as a map move event instead of a click. Increasing this value can make it easier to click on the map.

The changelog said:

> Some touch devices do not play well with OpenLayers's way of detecting clicks. To overcome this, a new `moveTolerance` option was introduced, so users can override the 1 pixel threshold above which a touch-release sequence won't be considered a click any more.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html